# How to convert a .Net Core 2.2 / Angular 8 app to PWA

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core, progressive-web-apps

I can create and test a basic Angular app to PWA following the angular docs. However, I can't get a .NET Core 2.2 / Angular 8 app (originally created using the Visual Studio Angular SPA Template) to a Progressive Web App.

I'm struggling to find any online help on how to do this. Everything from Microsoft is about converting an MVC app to PWA - nothing about converting an Angular SPA / .NET Core project to a PWA. And everything from the Angular side says nothing about the .NET Core Visual Studio scenario.

What I've done so far is as PWA support to the angular piece with via ng add @angular/pwa (and followed the entire angular PWA / Service Worker tutorial)

There is a nuget package from Microsoft for a .net core service worker but best as I can tell, that's not for an angular SPA (since it includes a service worker but I assume the one created by the ng add @angular/pwa is what I need).
https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker

I've tried various configurations in startup.cs but nothing seems to work, including skipping the

```
spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
```

and instead use

```
spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:8080")
```

and launched http-server -p 8080 -c -1 under the clientapp folder (per the Angular docs) manually (also tried launching it directly under the dist folder).

Neither the manifest nor the service worker loads after I publish to our IIS server (per chrome's dev tools).

If someone has a working version of startup.cs and other config files for this or some pointers it would much appreciated.

Comment: What are you talking about, there is no template for a PWA, turn off your internet on your computer are greatly throttle your data connection and start making features that still work and viola you have a PWA!

Comment: If you're using Angular as the front end and .net as the back end, you only need to worry about the Angular piece being the PWA since it'll be decoupled from your api. .Net doesn't need to know anything about your angular pwa and doesn't need any additional configuration. That web essentials repo is for a MVC template because .net does have the ability to render pages on the fly, but if you're using angular then everything is already compiled. You can place your built files inside the wwwroot, but at that point you're basically just combining two separate "projects".

Comment: @nullptr.t That is what I initially thought but what is throwing me is that after setting up the Angular front end and running the server locally via VS, the service-worker doesn't run at all. And when I publish to IIS, neither the manifest nor the service-worker are detected by the browser (dev tools shows the manifest is missing and the server worker isn't running). It must be a config issue on how I'm setting the Angular piece for PWA. At least I'm glad to hear it should work and it isn't some inherent incompatibility

Answer (score 1):

If you want a [guide to create a PWA with Angular](https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular) have a look at this article, where I explain the whole process step-by-step. Plus you will find a working Angular PWA example in Github.

The article is part of a [series about PWAs](https://dev.to/paco_ita/a-gentle-introduction-to-progressive-web-apps-step-1-24da), maybe you can have a look at them to get a better overview about this technology.

If you ran the schematic command: `ng add @angular/pwa` you should have already a service worker module installed on your client app. Plus a web manifest and a service worker config file (called ngsw-config.json) where you can specify caching strategies.

Therefore you should already be able to test your PWA locally, just be aware you need an http server and an Angular prod build to run the service worker locally, since ng serve does not work with the service worker.

Comment: Thanks, I did look at several articles and that may even have been one of them. Like I said, I did manage to get an Angular project working as a PWA. It is just when the Angular project is part of a .Net project running under Visual Studio that I see issues. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Do you load the 'dist' folder in IIS? Dist folder is filled  with the bundles after a prod build.

Comment: VS does that. It builds the project using ng build --prod and copies the dist folder to the server.

Comment: @Alex Did you get the solution for the same? I am also looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `ng build --prod` and copy the generated files:

- ngsw.json
- ngsw-worker.js
- safety-worker.js
- worker-basic.js

to the "src" folder.

Then, in angular.json, add them to the "assets" array like this:

[image]

*Don't forget to remove the files from src and from assets array for production